# Remove precentage sign in nested list

Tags: python

I`m trying to remove the % sign from nested list. All sublists can contains string element or integer element . My question, how can I remove the the % sign from the elements that contains % sign.

Example:

```
input:
[[Name, cnt , RSH, Total],
[XXXX, 000000093, 0.2% ,000000000 ,0.0%],
[YYYY, 000000064, 0.1% ,000000000 ,0.0%]]

output:
[[Name, cnt , RSH, Total],
[XXXX, 000000093, 0.2 ,000000000 ,0.0],
[YYYY, 000000064, 0.1 ,000000000 ,0.0]]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pythonic approach would be:

```
b = [[j.split('%')[0] for j in i] for i in a]
```

The output is:

```
 [['Name', 'cnt', 'RSH', 'Total'],
  ['XXXX', '000000093', '0.2', '000000000', '0.0'],
  ['YYYY', '000000064', '0.1', '000000000', '0.0']]
```